# Tablet Not Picking Up Images in xxxhdpi folder

Tags: android

I provided alternate sizes for all my icons hdpi, xxhdpi, etc I was hoping that the tablet will pick up the larger icons on /res/drawables/xxhdpi but that was not the case, both the phone and the tablet are picking up icons from res/drawables/hdpi

How can I make my tablets or any size beyond both sw-dp600dp and swdp820dp to pick up the images in res/drawable/xxhdpi?

I created a folder /res/drawables-sw600dp and places some icons there but they were not picked up.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your images are named exactly the same as in the hdpi folder? Also check the naming of your drawable-xxhdpi folder. Lastly double check your screen size using an app such as check my size or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablet, just like phone will pick up images based on its `dpi` value, so if tablet is `hdpi` device it will not use `xxhdpi` images. That is exact behavior you are observing.

In order to use larger images on tablet you have to provide folders named

```
drawable-sw600dp
```

You can also add `dpi` to such drawable folders like

```
drawable-sw600dp-mdpi
drawable-sw600dp-hdpi
drawable-sw600dp-xhdpi
...
```

Folder name `drawables-sw600dp` is not correct one, you have `drawables` instead of `drawable`.